# css Input boxes right below each other no matter what font size

Tags: html, css

I want these Input boxes to be right below each other, no matter what Font-Family, what font size or how the user moves the window. How is that with css possible?

[image]

At the moment I use the following method:

```
tab1 {
  padding-left: 5em;
}
```

That is lots of work, and if you change the text size or the fond-type you have to do it again.

Comment: How about `flexbox`?

Comment: Can you post your full code (including the html)? We can't help you just looking at an image

Comment: @B001ᛦ I will take a closer look at that!

Comment: Hello, you cannot use tab1 directly in CSS, First, check tab1 is id or class if id use `#tab1` else use `.tab1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: flex` in combo with `flex-direction: column`:

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="a" value="A">
  <input type="text" name="b" value="B">
  <input type="text" name="c" value="C">
  <input type="text" name="d" value="D">
</form>
```